# OS X in VM Ware or Virtual Box

Tags: virtualization, vmware, virtualbox

Is it possible to run OS X in VM Ware? I want to setup a virtualized OS X for testing instead of going to buy another mac. Can I do that technically and legally?

To be explicit I do own a mac already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it technically. Legally I think you can do it if a) The VM is on Mac hardware and b) you purchase a unique disk (license) for the OS in the VM.

Comment: There is one other condition: the OS in the VM has to be Mac OS X Server. Regular Mac OS X will not install.

Comment: What about Lion or Mountain Lion: there is no CD for these OS